# "How to fix nginx: [emerg] "fastcgi_cache" zone "wpcache" is unknown in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf"

Tags: nginx, server, centos, vps, fastcgi

I tried to fix it but when I ran, it couldn't work.Can anybody guide me how to fix it?
Nginx 16.0 and Centos Linux 7.
Thanks

Srv Log:

```
ul 08 13:29:13 150-95-105-126 systemd[1]: Starting The NGINX HTTP and reverse proxy server...
Jul 08 13:29:13 150-95-105-126 nginx[29274]: nginx: [emerg] "fastcgi_cache" zone "wpcache" is unknown in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:96
Jul 08 13:29:13 150-95-105-126 nginx[29274]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Jul 08 13:29:13 150-95-105-126 systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 08 13:29:13 150-95-105-126 systemd[1]: Failed to start The NGINX HTTP and reverse proxy server.
Jul 08 13:29:13 150-95-105-126 systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
Jul 08 13:29:13 150-95-105-126 systemd[1]: nginx.service failed
```

Answer (score 1):

Configure NGINX to enable FastCGI caching.
To set this up we will need to make changes in NGINX server block. Possibly in default configuration file:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

In this configuration file enter the following lines above and outside the server{ } block:

```
fastcgi_cache_path /var/run/nginx-fastcgi-cache levels=1:2 
keys_zone=wpcache:100m inactive=60m;
```

The fastcgi_cache_path directive specifies the location of the cache, it's size, key_zone name, subdirectory levels, and the inactive timer.

The cache directory /var/cache/nginx must exist and be writable for nginx:

```
mkdir /var/cache/nginx
chown www-data:www-data /var/cache/nginx
```

From the docs

> Syntax:   fastcgi_cache_path path [levels=levels] [use_temp_path=on|off] keys_zone=name:size [inactive=time] [max_size=size] [min_free=size] [manager_files=number] [manager_sleep=time] [manager_threshold=time] [loader_files=number] [loader_sleep=time] [loader_threshold=time] [purger=on|off] [purger_files=number] [purger_sleep=time] [purger_threshold=time];
> Default:    —
> Context:    http

The link to [official docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_cache_path)
Other helpful links
[Configuration of FastCGI cache](https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/blogblogwordpress-caching-solutions-part-2---configuring-nginx-fastcgi-static-page-caching-and-final-load-testing_328726)
[Optimazing of FastCGI cache](https://tweenpath.net/tuning-nginx-for-maximum-performance/)